# AgGrid Angular cellRenderer Dropdown layer problem

Tags: angular, typescript, z-index, ag-grid-angular

I want to build a Angular Component implementing the [AgGrid cellRenderer Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#cell-renderer-component-1) interface.

The html of the component:

```html
<div dropdown>
  <div>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle aria-controls="dropdown-1" type="button">{{ params.getLabel(params.value) }}</a>
  </div>
  <ul id="dropdown-1" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let item of params.items">
      <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="item.action(params.value)">{{ item.label }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It uses the [cellRendererParams](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#reference-ICellRendererParams) to get a list of Dropdown items like this:

```js
cellRendererParams: {
        getLabel: (field: any) => {
          return field;
        },
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Edit',
            action: (field: any) => {
              console.log('edit');
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }
```

And the Problem is that the Dropdown renderes behind the next rows of the table.

[image]
1st Row

[image]
2nd Row

I thought it could be with the z-index or trying other css like position relative or absolute.
I cant get it from rendering behind the row.